# Non-destructive Git checkout in dirty work tree ($HOME/.dotfiles)

Tags: git, git-checkout, dotfiles, working-copy

This problem came up while scheming up another Git `.dotfiles` management system. I want to use `$HOME` as my working tree and have the repository stored elsewhere (not under `.git` as that confuses other repositories).

On old machines with previously copied and potentially tweaked dotfiles, I'd now like to clone my new dotfiles repository and (*wave hands*) get to a state where I can see the (pre-)existing state of my `$HOME/.*` dotfiles as modifications to the master of my newly cloned repository. This is mostly background, in **Git I just want to cautiously checkout in a dirty directory without overwriting**.

(In an ordinary case I could just start in a new directory and then copy in my changes, but that seems hard to do when the work-tree is my `$HOME`.)

I found one pair of commands that seems to get me to the right place, but I'm
not sure if there are either pitfalls to this approach or simpler ways to do
the same thing:

```
git read-tree -v HEAD # load HEAD into the index
git checkout-index -a # cautiously check out all files without overwriting
```

Do these two commands get to the same state as copying away my home, doing an ordinary checkout, then copying back my files, such that `git diff` would have just the changes I'd done on this machine and no files deleted?

Are there other options to these that should be applied?

The context is my (alpha) bootstrap script:

```
git clone --bare -n git://github.com/$(git config github.user)/.dotfiles.git ~/.dotfiles/repo.git
git config -f .dotfiles/repo.git/config core.bare false
git config -f .dotfiles/repo.git/config core.logallrefupdates true
git config -f .dotfiles/repo.git/config core.worktree $HOME
export GIT_DIR=~/.dotfiles/repo.git ;  export GIT_WORK_TREE=~
git read-tree -v HEAD 
git checkout-index -a # all files without overwriting
ln -sf $HOME/.dotfiles/gitignore-dots $HOME/.dotfiles/repo.git/info/exclude
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use $HOME as my working tree and have the repository stored elsewhere
> (not under .git as that confuses other repositories).

Don't do this. What I do is

put your working tree here

```
/opt/dotfiles
```

put your repo here

```
/opt/dotfiles/.git
```

Then you can bootstrap the working tree to `$HOME` by running

```
. /opt/dotfiles/bootstrap.sh
```

Famous example, and my example here

## [mathiasbynens bootstrap.sh](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/bootstrap.sh)

## [svnpenn bootstrap.sh](https://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/master/bootstrap.sh)

Comment: Could you clarify the "Don't do this"?  Is there a risk inherent in my approach to be wary of?  What are the advantages to rsync-ing repo→$HOME?  Thank you

Comment: `$HOME` is a much used directory and should not be the site of a git working directory; almost certain working directory would become contaminated

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2012-08-19

I've been using this scheme to setup my dotfiles on new and existing accounts for a little while now and the above commands haven't destroyed anything to date.
On the other hand, no git experts have expressed approval of this arrangement
and some have been disapproving in a vaguely "are you mad?" kind of way.

I now have aliases doton/dotoff and sourced files which adjust GIT_DIR and GIT_WORK_TREE,
so I make a tweak at work, try it, push to github then update my other machines at home.
Most of the time it is an easy fast-forward or rebase, but occasionally a dirty
update is required.

#### Dirty Update

I'm adding this here as it's the other half of the approach sketched in the question.

Say I git add my ~/.XCompose and push it.  When I want to pull this to a machine
that already has an .XCompose file, I want to fetch the change, see the diff to my
local (unadded) copy and merge from there.
Git checks for this and bails out, which is usually appropriate.

Again I'm using plumbing commands to do most of a higher level command,
but without some of those pesky safety checks in order to work with a
dirty working copy.  The plumbing commands aren't as well covered in docs
but seem to work (no guarantee).

These instructions assume that you have no new local changes,
ie. it doesn't do a rebase.

(*Note that this may end up trashing files*, including untracked ones.
I don't know if this is anywhere close to safe and I suspect that
if something goes wrong you could be left with quite a mess.)

```
git fetch # download FETCH_HEAD

# Check HEAD is an ancestor of FETCH_HEAD
cmp <( git rev-parse HEAD ) <( git merge-base HEAD FETCH_HEAD ) \
    || echo "merge-base is not HEAD, not fast forward"

# merge FETCH_HEAD into HEAD in index (2 tree merge is ff, no local changes)
# (no -u means the work tree is not updated)
git read-tree -v -m  HEAD FETCH_HEAD # --trivial ?
# index now merged with FETCH_HEAD

# set HEAD to be FETCH_HEAD with dereferencing
git update-ref HEAD FETCH_HEAD

# update work tree without overwriting existing files (not forced)
# (existing un-added isn't overwritten)
git checkout-index -a

# can now check diffs for conflicts add either commit/edit/checkout
git diff --stat

git pull -vn # should be a no-op
```

Here's some commands I use to check the state of things:

```
git rev-parse HEAD FETCH_HEAD   # what do they point to
git diff --stat HEAD FETCH_HEAD # differences
git merge-base HEAD FETCH_HEAD  # common ancestor
for r in HEAD FETCH_HEAD; do echo $r ; git log --oneline $r | head -1; done
git name-rev $( git merge-base HEAD FETCH_HEAD )

# peek at index
git ls-files --directory --exclude-standard --stage

git diff-index --cached FETCH_HEAD # see "local changes" carried forward
```